# Determining your websites color scheme

Tags: user-interface, web, color-scheme, color-management

One of the biggest issues I have, from a UI standpoint, when building a new website is figuring out what colors I will use and of those colors, do they actually work well together. 

I found this site that has really helped me out and I figured I would share it with all of you and also get some responses back about either sites similar or other ways that you get/figure out your color schemes.

Here is the site that I currently use: http://kuler.adobe.com/

With Adobe Kuler, you can chose a base color and it will suggest 5 colors, including your color, that go well with one another. You can, of course, modify the colors it chooses. Also,one of the main features I use, is the image color matching. You can upload an image and it will determine a color scheme based on the colors of the image. So if you have a logo and want to use the colors of the logo, then this works perfectly for you.

Thank you and I look forward to your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kuler is pretty nice.  I also like http://www.degraeve.com/color-palette/ for just creating a color scheme based on an image, and http://www.colourlovers.com/ for picking colors that go nicely together.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Color Brewer](http://www.personal.psu.edu/faculty/c/a/cab38/ColorBrewer/ColorBrewer.html).  It reports on where the color would be useful (projector, laptop, printed page, etc.) and if the colors are color-blind friendly.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Colour Schemer in the past, which had a pretty simple interface:

http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are two that I like:

http://www.colorcombos.com/combotester.html

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

I also like http://kuler.adobe.com/ that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Color scheme from logo or any image: online tool where you can upload image/logo and it gives you out a suggested color scheme that matches your logo/image.

Here is the link http://www.pictaculous.com/

Answer (score 0):

Some pre-made pallets can give inspiration. My favourite is Google Material Colors which has a sleek website [here](https://penguoir.github.io/Google-Material-Colors/#).